# How to disable the HTML class warning "class not found" in Netbeans 11.0

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-11

I would like to disable the warnings Netbeans is throwing when it's not finding classes because it's flooding my IDE.

For example, for this bit of code:

```
<div class="portlet light">
    <a class="navigation" href="/home">Home page</a>
</div>
```

I have 3 warnings about the class being not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to: `Tools` > `Options` > `Editor` > `Hints`

Then in `Language` select `HTML`

Under CSS, uncheck `Missing CSS Class` and `Missing CSS Class In Partials`